# Why is the output of a Node AES128 Cipher 32 bytes long?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes

Here is my code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
function aese (key) {
    return crypto.createCipher('aes128', key)
}

var x1 = crypto.randomBytes(16)
var y1 = crypto.randomBytes(16)

var a = aese(y1)
a.write(x1)
a.end()
var ct = a.read()
console.log(ct.length); //should be 16 but is 32
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's an IV.

Comment: Sorry it should be `ct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the padding that adds at least one byte, 16 bytes in gives at least 17 out which is padded to 32 due to the block size.

Try decreasing the number of encrypted bytes to 15 and you'll get 16 bytes as output.

Another option is to [turn off padding](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_auto_padding_true);

```
var x1 = crypto.randomBytes(16)
var y1 = crypto.randomBytes(16)

var a = aese(y1)
a.setAutoPadding(false);   <--- turn of auto-padding
a.write(x1)
a.end()
var ct = a.read()
console.log(ct.length);    <--- gives 16 as output
```